# npm install error ( npm install -g angular-cli ) in windows 10 64 bit

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

While installing angular on my machine I am getting the below error. Uninstall and installed Node multiple times. But it is not helping. I have given the error log below. Can anyone help me in sorting this?

```
3 silly resolveWithNewModule universal-analytics@0.4.20 checking installable status
324 silly pacote version manifest for uuid@7.0.2 fetched in 298ms
325 silly resolveWithNewModule uuid@7.0.2 checking installable status
326 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
327 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 9824ms
328 verbose stack Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\Shally.BBYBSDC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\1f\85\3e0b21cc5deb10a0dc51ed6dace9f5ae0f08f66b5c064b262517165cfa2f'
329 verbose cwd C:\Users\Shally.BBYBSDC
330 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
331 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
332 verbose node v14.4.0
333 verbose npm  v6.14.5
334 error code UNKNOWN
335 error syscall open
336 error path C:\Users\Shally.BBYBSDC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\1f\85\3e0b21cc5deb10a0dc51ed6dace9f5ae0f08f66b5c064b262517165cfa2f
337 error errno -4094
338 error UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\Shally.BBYBSDC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\1f\85\3e0b21cc5deb10a0dc51ed6dace9f5ae0f08f66b5c064b262517165cfa2f'
339 verbose exit [ -4094, true ]
```

Comment: you tried this npm install -g @angular/cli
 or the one you wrote in question ?

Comment: i tried npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: probably cli is not supported at the node version you are using.

Try using LTS version of nodejs that will fix this issue.